# Call play(), stop() on hidden <embed> tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a simulation page for an application. It requires a set of button controls to **Play, Pause and Stop** sample music. I read some questions on stackoverflow to get the controls working. 
Some questions that I referred were:

- [Accessing hidden embedded quicktime audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71899/accessing-hidden-embedded-quicktime-audio)
- [How to USE <embed> tag for music player control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16085047/how-to-use-embed-tag-for-music-player-control)
- [how can use JavaScript to control audio in the embed tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14497631/how-can-use-javascript-to-control-audio-in-the-embed-tag)
- [Cross-platform, cross-browser way to play sound from Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187098/cross-platform-cross-browser-way-to-play-sound-from-javascript)

My problem starts when I set hidden="true" in embed tag and try to call javascript function. I have tried putting  tag in a hidden div but it does not work.

Embed tag code:

```
<embed src="abc.mp3" AutoStart="false"  loop="false" height="0" width="0" hidden="true" />
```

Javascript to access embed tag methods.

```
document.embeds[0].Play();
```

cheers

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? There is no function called `Play()`. It is spelled `play()`.

Comment: Embed is now deprecated and only supported by browsers for compatibility of old websites, it might be removed from major browsers soon.

To display a picture, it is better to use the <img> tag. To display HTML, it is better to use the <iframe> tag. To display video or audio, it is better to use the <video> and <audio> tags.

Answer (score 0):

try Call play(), stop() script

```
<BGSOUND id="BGSOUND_ID" LOOP=1 SRC="jsilence.mid">

<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
<!--
function playSound(audioURL) {
 if (document.all) document.all['BGSOUND_ID'].src=audioURL;
 else self.iplayer.location.replace('jsplayer.htm?'+audioURL);
}

function stopSound() {
 if (document.all) document.all['BGSOUND_ID'].src='jsilence.mid';
 else self.iplayer.location.replace('jsplayer.htm?stop');
}
//-->
</script>

<form name=myform>
<input type=button value="Play Sound" onClick="playSound('Bach.mid')">
<input type=button value="Stop Sound" onClick="stopSound()">
</form>
```

Comment: thanks, I also need to have a pause button to pause the music.

Answer (score 0):

I've got two possible things that are making your code not working as expected:

- What about if there is a previous embed in your document? I would set an id attribute for your audio  and use document.getElementById("theId").play() instead of document.embeds[0].play()
- Are you using Play() with capital P? Don't know if it's just a typo but could be also the error.

Hidden or visible it should work the same way,

hope it helps someone ;)